# Trying to achieve simple fail over for two VMs hosted on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

i am running a web-based online application and trying to achieve HA.
i created two windows vmss in an availability set.

All i am looking for is a simple failover protocol, what i am trying to achieve is when my Main Vm is down for any reason,my incoming traffic redirects to my Backup VM till the main vm is up and running again.

I know that Azure Traffic Manager can achieve this by using the Priority type and setting end points for Public Ips that assigned to my vmss.

But the traffic manager is using DNS in order to route traffics, there are some downtown before the traffic manager redirect traffic to my backup vm.

Please check this answer as well for more info why Traffic manager is not the solution. -even when i use fast-intervals settings-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34469575/10786981

i also can't use load-balancer. As i need the Active/Passive model and load-balancer can't support this model.

A 3rd Load Balancer are expensive and we are really looking in to a simple solution here.

Comment: azure load balancer with proper health probes

Comment: i am not sure how to set up load balance's health probes to achieve what i need. i checked out this answer and load balance doesn't support Active/Passive model. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b60801ed-5692-48f2-95fc-5f6e24ea09bd/active-passive-load-balancer-setup-in-azure?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork

Comment: well, it doesnt mean you cannot create a config that will look like its active\passive. but you probably need to take a step back, something looks fishy here